# Recover gcrypt git repository from expired GPG keys

Tags: git, encryption, gnupg

I had been using an encrypted git repository using [git-remote-gcrypt](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt) when I started getting the following message when running `git fetch`.

```
$ git fetch
gcrypt: Decrypting manifest
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
gcrypt: Failed to decrypt manifest!
```

I believe I am getting this message because my GPG key expired a couple days ago. How can I recover and gain access to the repository again?

Answer (score 1):

Update your keys by either creating a new key or extending your expiration date. Export and give your new public keys to your team members. Have them import your new public key into GPG and have them push a new commit.

From this point you should be able to `git fetch` and get the latest contents from git.

I couldn't find a way to fix the issue only from my view of the repository. The correct thing to do is to NOT let your keys expire. In other words, update and publish your keys well before they expire. Then you'll never end up seeing this error message from gcrypt.